# height of tabwidget

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget

I have a TabWidget done so:

[image]

I have tried to reduce the height and I get this:

[image]

with the following code:

```
    <TabWidget android:id="@android:id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent" 
        android:layout_height="40px" 
        android:layout_marginTop="10px" ></TabWidget>
```

There is no way to make the text disappear?